# Implement custom operators with GDB python API

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

As an example lets say I have a linked list implemented in C. Can I use the GDB python API to implement a custom array access operator so that I can get a value from the list like `myList[0]` while debugging?

Have tried reading through the docs but could find nothing on it

Comment: With the [XMethod API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Xmethod-API.html) this should be possible, but I don't actually know if this would work for C as well (since you can't define `operator[]` in C).

Comment: Thank you! That half works it seems.
I can define xmethods, but they don't seem to run for C (I need to set the language to c++ and then they run)

Comment: @YupDeDup Indeed.  The XMethod API is designed to provide C++ operators - often these operators are inlined in compiled code and so not available for GDB to call while debugging.  As C has no operator overload feature the XMethods are not applied when debugging C code.